# Regular expression for numeric values and a single decimal place in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Attempting to parse only numeric values and a single decimal place with the following regular expression but characters are also being parsed.  Any ideas?

```
<?php 
function get_rate1(SimpleXMLElement $xml) {

    $exchange['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[15]->description;
    $rate = preg_replace("/^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*)$/", '', $exchange['rate']);

    echo $rate . '<br />'; 
    return $rate;
}
?>
```

Expected results:

```
11.20409
```

Actual results:

```
1 British Pound Sterling = 1.20409 Euro
```

Desired Results:

```
1.20409
```

Furthermore, any ideas how to remove the first numeric value as the number 1 displayed prior to *British Pound Sterling* would make the value incorrect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}", $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
} else {
    throw new Exception("GIVE ME NUMBERS, lol");
}
```

On `"This is a text 1.234 with a number"` should give `"1.2"`

Does not match numbers like `.123`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the regex should be:

```
'/\d*\.\d/'
```

this will match any number of digits (0 or more) before the decimal, and exactly one past it.  There are some other problems with Frits van Campen's regex, particularly an unclosed paren.